# How to concatenate text to text on multiple web pages

Tags: javascript, string, text, concatenation

I have a website that contains a specific string of characters on every page, *"Fish and Sons"*. What I need is to add *", LLC"* to the end of this string across the entire website, in every place it exists.

I have the following JS added, but it isn't working. What do I need to change so I don't have to manually add *", LLC"* to every instance of *"Fish and Sons"*?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let name = document.body.innerHTML.search("Fish and Sons")
  const llc = ", LLC"
  
    if (name) {
        name += llc
    }

}
```

Comment: Two things: 1. you're missing the ) to close the `ready` call and 2. are you sure you are willing to trade of compute time **every** time the page is loaded for a couple of search and replaces or even a `grep` + `sed`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.replaceAll()` function for this. After you add the 'LLC', you have to update the innerHTML.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = (document.body.innerHTML).replaceAll("Fish and Sons", "Fish and Sons, LLC");
}
```

```html
<b>Fish and Sons</b>
```

This will replace all the occurrences of `Fish and Sons` with `Fish and Sons, LLC` with the `replaceAll` function.

**With Regex:** If you only want to replace the occurrences of `Fish and Sons` that **aren't** already followed by the `llc`, you can use regex:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var regex = /Fish and Sons(?!, LLC)/gm
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll(regex, "Fish and Sons, LLC")
}
```

```html
<b>Fish and Sons</b><br>
<b>Fish and Sons, LLC</b>
```

This way, if it already contains `, LLC` it won't add another one. Notice the second 'Fish and Sons' already has a ', LLC', so it doesn't add another one.